# What part of speech does the word warm function as in the expression "stay warm"?

Tags: grammaticality

Last week, as I was departing from work, a co-worker said, "Stay warm!" It was very cold that day. My question is how is the word warm functioning in this sentence? What part of speech is it? It appears to be modifying the word stay, but stay is a verb and warm is an adjective.  My understanding is that adjectives cannot modify verbs. Please explain?

Comment: It's an ordinary adjective acting as a subject-oriented complement of the verb *stay* predicated of the implicit subject *you*.

Comment: It's no different to other imperatives such as *"Be quiet!"* or *"Get real!"*. It would take some serious creative interpretation to parse those commands if they used explicitly adverbial forms, but there are some constructions where both work. You can certainly use *"Come quickly!"* and *"Come quick!"* more or less interchangeably.

Comment: ... as opposed to humorous creative interpretation?

Comment: A separate issue is why there is no infinitive complementizer _to be_ required with _stay warm_, like there is in _continue/want/desire/intend/remember/try to be warm_, or a gerund _be_, like _stop/finish/remember/try being warm_. _Stay_ seems unusual in this property.

Comment: @JohnLawler No more unusual than any other linking verb, surely? _Stay/remain/keep/be/get/appear warm_ …

Comment: Calling them "linking verbs" because they don't use _to_ and then saying they're no different from other linking verbs in lacking _to_ is not a helpful approach. This is one reason linguists don't normally use the term.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the sentence *Stay warm* is an implied *you*. The adjective *warm* modifies the implied pronoun *you*. The verb *stay* serves as a [linking verb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/linking%20verb) connecting the subject with its modifier.

A similar construction is *Be safe.* The adjective *safe* modifies *you* (implied), linked by *be*.