# I posted a question on this website, but I am not sure if I punctuated it correctly

Tags: grammaticality

I posted [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227673/what-part-of-speech-does-the-word-warm-function-as-in-the-expression-stay-warm) on this website, but I am not sure if I punctuated it correctly. The sentence in question is “What part of speech does the word warm function as in the expression ‘Stay warm’”?   I am not sure if I should include the exclamation point at the end of the sentence with in the quotation or omit it.  If a question mark is used, should I place it inside the quotation marks or out outside or inside of the quotation marks at the end of the sentence? Would it be grammatically correct to use and exclamation point and a question mark at the end of the sentence?  In addition, should the world warm be in italic or bold text since the questions is about that particular word and the answer will involve a discussion of the word?

Which question is punctuated correctly?

> (1)  What part of speech does the word warm function as in the expression “Stay warm!”
>
> (2) What part of speech does the word warm function as in the expression “Stay warm?”
>
> (3) What part of speech does the word warm function as in the expression “Stay warm”?
>
> (4)  What part of speech does the word warm function as in the expression “Stay warm!”?

Comment: I'm wondering if the words "does function as" are necessary. I suggest the following: What part of speech is the word "warm" in the expression "Stay warm!"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good alternative. I'd use (4), which is most logical, but displeasing in appearance. Second choice is (3), which leaves it implicit that the quoted expression is an exclamation (but it's obvious).  (1) and (2) seem completely wrong.

Comment: I agree. And you should quote _warm_ in _the word "warm"_, as long as you're quoting _"Stay warm"_, whatever the other punctuation.