# What part of speech is 'put' in the expression 'stay put'?

Tags: parts-of-speech

A [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227673/what-part-of-speech-does-the-word-warm-function-as-in-the-expression-stay-warm) asked the same of 'warm' in 'stay warm' but the single answer was not very satisfying to me and also 'put' is not the same as 'warm' even if, as the answer suggests, 'you' is implied by the invitation 'stay'.

The context of 'stay put' is that I saw a picture of a second world war bomb shelter in England and the last of the instructions was to : 10. Stay put.

It is an imperative, neither an invitation nor a colloquial farewell.

'Put' could be viewed as an adverb, modifying the verb 'stay'. One is to stay in a putly way, as it were.

Or 'put' could be viewed as the past participle and the idea is to 'stay' as one was originally placed. Stay as one had been 'put'.

The expression is imperative and it is more than an imperative for one is not only to stay, as such, one is to stay exactly there and not move. Or else.

I like the expression and had not seen or heard it for a while.

The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stay+put&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstay%20put%3B%2Cc0) shows that both AmE and BrE have a hump during the second world war, a decline thereafter and a rise since then, which is an interesting observation on post-war and modern attitudes, I would say (as a baby boomer).

So, what part of speech, may I ask ?

Comment: I think it’s quite simply a past participle.

Comment: Morphologically it's a past participle, but syntactically I'd say it's *functioning* as an adjective/adverb: *We should stay **put** / He will stay **hidden** / I can't stay **silent** / It stayed **upright** / ...*

Comment: Patricia T. O’Conner and Stewart Kellerman, in [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/02/stay-put.html), give a good overview of this. They _do_ look at why 'put' is in this unusual place, there being a suggestion a deleted form of 'stay [where (you have been)] put' (etc) is in play, but wisely don't go into the analysis of the POS of 'put' here (an ex-verb?). It's best to regard _stay put_ as an extragrammatical idiom. And probably not so 'vulgar' nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merriam-Webster Dictionary [2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put) calls "put" an adjective in "stay put".  Like stay sharp, stay happy, stay alert.

[image: Definition of "Put"]

---

> put adjective
>
> Definition of put (Entry 3 of 3)
>
> : being in place : FIXED, SET
>
> stay put until I call

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put)

Comment: @Nigel J, done.

Comment: Try it now.  I'm learning the format as I go.  I had to look it up.

Comment: I have added a link in the way usually done on the site. You will be able to see how it is done.

Comment: The Tour Page gives three different ways it can be done.  I used one of those ways.  Are you saying that only one way is actually acceptable?

Comment: Okay, so this is what you want when I reference something by name?  Got it.

[Merriam Webster][3]
[3]:https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put